# Solspace Calendar occurrence_id

Tags: solspace, calendar

I'm using Solspace Calendar 1.8.14 in ExpressionEngine 2.10.1. According to the Solspace Calendar documentation (https://solspace.com/expressionengine/calendar/docs/occurrences/#occurrence_id) I should be able to display a unique ID for each event occurrence; however, when I try to display this ID it only shows the shared event_id instead of a unique ID.

Example:

```
{exp:calendar:occurrences event_id='71' date_range_start='today' date_range_end='12 month' upcoming_occurrences_limit='20'}
    <p>ID: {occurrence_id}</p>
{/exp:calendar:occurrences}
```

In the above case, `{occurrence_id}` displays '71' for each occurrence. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Brady

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the documentation being a little vague about this, but this is ONLY available for "custom edited occurrences", which means recurrences that are not just "phantom" ones, but have been edited through the Calendar control panel to create unique field data (title, custom fields, etc) for that particular occurrence. What Calendar does is has to create another channel entry to hold that data. Only occurrences such as these will have a unique occurrence ID (which is the entry ID) that can be filtered on, etc. :)

Comment: So then what is the point of the occurrences if you can't reference to them unless you go and manually edit each one of them through the control panel? Seems like a pointless feature then since you can't in any way identify if someone select that occurrence or anything.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you intend on using Calendar. If you're not trying to allow some sort of attempt at "booking requests", Calendar seems to work fine for most customers. Each recurrence will display as if it's a "real" one in the templates, and there's a way to get each of them to appear with the right date on a single entry detail page (see demo templates).